# Getting large negative numbers printing arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello Im getting negative valhes when trying to output some variables to the screen.

Ive looked this up and in most cases its an uninitialized variable but I cant find anything wrong.

Saying I have too much code to text ratio but I really dont know how to reiterate so heres some filler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int Input;
    int WepType;
    string Weapon;
    string WeaponType;

    int Stats[3];
    int AtkStats[4];


cout << "Pick your weapon.\n" << endl;
cout << "{===================================================}\n";
cout << "[                                                   ]\n";
cout << "[  Iron Longsword              Sharp Fishing Spear  ]\n";
cout << "[         1                                         ]\n";           
cout << "[                                                   ]\n";     
cout << "[              Ornate Hunting Bow                   ]\n";
cout << "[                                                   ]\n";
cout << "{===================================================}\n";

//Weapon Selection
 cin >> Input;

    if(Input == 1)
    {
     WepType     = 1;
     Weapon      = "Iron Longsword";
     WeaponType  = "OneHanded";
     Stats[0]    = Stats[0] + 10;
     Stats[1]    = Stats[1] + 0;
     Stats[2]    = Stats[2] + 0;
     AtkStats[0] = AtkStats[0] + 10;
     AtkStats[1] = AtkStats[1] + 0;
     AtkStats[2] = AtkStats[2] + 0;
     AtkStats[3] = AtkStats[3] + 0;


    cout << "Weapon      = " << Weapon      << endl;
    cout << "Weapon Type = " << WeaponType  << endl;
    cout << "Health      = " << Stats[0]    << endl;
    cout << "Physical    = " << AtkStats[0] << endl;
    cout << "Light       = " << AtkStats[1] << endl;
    cout << "Dark        = " << AtkStats[2] << endl;
    cout << "Temporal    = " << AtkStats[3] << endl;
    }



      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
int Stats[3];
int AtkStats[4];
```

You should do:

```
int Stats[3] = {0, 0, 0};
int AtkStats[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Or as BlastFurnace pointed out in the comments (which I forgot about):

```
int Stats[3] = {}; // Initialize all elements to zero.
int AtkStats[4] = {};
```

In order to initialize the values. Right now they are just random junk, so when you assign, you get errors.

Comment: Thanks dude!  Would you happen to know what use for being able to use arrays in the manner I was?

Comment: If you just do `int Stats[3] = {};` all the elements will be value initialized (0 in this case).

Comment: @Blastfurnace Right, forgot about that. I'll add that as well.

Comment: @MoreUmph I'm not sure what you mean "manner you were." Just initialize them properly.